# Proving $(AB)^{\top} = B^{\top} A^{\top}$ using linear maps

Tags: linear-transformations

For $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and $n \times p$ $B$, I know how to prove $(AB)^{\top} = B^{\top} A^{\top}$ using summations and the definition of multiplication. I want to prove this more formally using dual maps, but can't figure out how to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove such a statement for abstract linear maps, then forget matrices and $\Bbb R^n$.

Let $T:V \to W$ be linear, so that $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ is given by $T^*(f)=f\circ T$. You can show that if $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are bases for $V$ and $W$ with dual bases $\mathcal{B}^*$ and $\mathcal{C}^*$, then $[T^*]_{\mathcal{C}^*,\mathcal{B}^*}=[T]_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}}^\top$. So what's next is indeed what you want.

Assume that $S:Z \to V$ is another linear map. Then $$(T\circ S)^*(f) = f \circ(T\circ S) = (f\circ T)\circ S = S^*(f\circ T) = S^*(T^*(f)).$$So $(T\circ S)^* = S^*\circ T^*$.

Comment: I understand everything you wrote, but I am having trouble tying this back to $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$. I know that each of these matrices are really linearly operators, but am unable to map this back to $T$ and $S$, as you've written them.

Comment: Write $A$ and $B$ for $T$ and $S$ then. Then $A^\top$ and $B^\top$ will stand for $T^*$ and $S^*$. The thing is that there are some isomorphisms going on under the rug, and I just didn't use any of them.

Comment: In that case, we have $[(T \circ S)*] = [T \circ S]^T$ and $[S* \circ T*] = [(S* \circ T*)*]^T$, and because $(T \circ S)* = S* \circ T*$, their matrices are the same. Is that right? If so, the only remaining question I have is on unpacking $(S* \circ T*)*$. Is that just $T \circ S$?

Comment: Applying $*$ on something that already has a $*$ leads you to bidual spaces, which is one of the many isomorphisms under the rug. Your problem is mostly notation, not math. One last attempt: write $A = [T]$ and $B=[S]$. Then: $$(AB)^\top = ([T][S])^\top = [T\circ S]^\top = [(T\circ S)^*] = [S^*\circ T^*] = [S^*][T^*]=[S]^\top [T]^\top = B^\top A^\top.$$

Comment: I think the only remaining thing I am confused on is the steps $([T][S])^T = [T \circ S]^T$ and $[S* \circ T^*] = [S*][T*]$. Is this definitional or an isomorphism? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: The matrix representing a composition of linear maps is the product of the matrices representing each linear map. This is the motivation for the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map. The dual map $g : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is the unique linear map given by $$\langle f(x), y \rangle_m = \langle x, g(y) \rangle_n,$$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_k$ denotes the Euclidian inner product on $\mathbb{R}^k$. If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is the representation of $f$ with respect to the standard bases, i.e., $f(x) = Ax$, then $A^T$ is the representation of the dual map $g$ with respect to the standard bases. Now returning to the task at hand. We have $$\langle ABx,y \rangle_m = \langle Bx,A^T y \rangle_n = \langle x,B^T A^T y \rangle_p.$$
It follows that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.